I want to check the positive definiteness of the matrix $\Lambda$
Background
We consider independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables $$X_1,\ldots, X_n \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} N_p(0, \Sigma).$$
Setup
Let $\Sigma$ be a $p$th order positive definite matrix.
In addition, we define
$$\Lambda = \Sigma^{-1/2} S \Sigma^{-1/2},
$$
where $S$ is the sample variance-covariance matrix, i.e., $S=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_iX^T_i$.
Question
Can we then say that $\Lambda$ is a positive definite matrix?
Related to this question

I assume you meant that $$S=\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iX_i^T $$
and that $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is the symmetric square root of Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse $\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}$.
Then, $$
\Lambda=\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}X_iX_i^T\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}=\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}X_iX_i^T\left[\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}\right]^T.$$
For any $u\in\mathbb{R}^p$,
$$
u^T\Lambda u=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}u^T\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}X_iX_i^T\left[\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}\right]^Tu=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\Vert X_i^T\left[\left(\Sigma^+\right)^{1/2}\right]^Tu \right\Vert^2.
$$
Since each summand $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert^2$ is non-negative, their average $u^T\Lambda u \ge 0$, i.e., $\Lambda$ is (symmetric) positive semidefinite. But it's not necessarily positive definite (almost surely), which, I think, would require $\Sigma$ to be positive definite in the first place.

Edited after the original question changed to "positive definite" $\Sigma$:
Following the previous argument, assume $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is the symmetric square root matrix.
For any non-zero $u\in\mathbb{R}^p$, let $v=\left[\Sigma^{-1/2}\right]^Tu$. Obviously, $v \ne {0}$ since otherwise $v^Tv=u^T\Sigma^{-1} u=0$ will violate the positive definiteness assumption of $\Sigma$. Now,
$$u^T\Lambda u = \frac1n\sum_i^n \left\lVert X_i^T v\right\rVert^2.
$$
As above, it remains to check the sign of each summand
$
\left\lVert X_i^T v\right\rVert^2.
$
As $v$ is not $0$, it has to have some non-zero elements. Let $N$ denote the set of such indices. In order for $
\left\lVert X_i^T v\right\rVert^2 = 0
$, we need
$$
\sum_{j=1}^p (X_{ij}v_j)^2 = \sum_{j\in N} (X_{ij}v_j)^2 = 0, $$i.e., $$X_{ij}=0 \ \forall\ j\in N.$$
This trivially has probability $0$, since $X_i$ has an absolutely continuous distribution. Therefore,
$$
P\left(u^T\Lambda u = 0\right) = 0\ \text{for any}\ u\ne0,
$$
i.e., $\Lambda$ is positive definite with probability $1$.

For any matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$, the matrix $S = X X^T$ is positive semi-definite. To see this, note that for all vectors $u \in \mathbb{R}^k$, we have $u^T S u = \|X^T u\|_2^2 \geq 0$. However, there could be null vectors such that $u^T S u = 0$ so it is only guaranteed to be semidefinite.
Additionally, you state that $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite, in which case it too can have null vectors. When that happens I assume that $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is understood in terms of the generalized inverse. If so, then any null vector of $\Sigma$ is also a null vector of $\Sigma^{-1/2} S \Sigma^{-1/2}$. For any null vector $v$ of $S$, there is typically also a null vector $w = \Sigma^{1/2} v$ of $\Sigma^{-1/2} S \Sigma^{-1/2}$.

Note that $S$ and $\Lambda$ will be positive semidefinite but typically not positive definite.  This can cause theoretical problems with degenerate probability distributions.  It can also cause practical numerical computing problems (e.g. the Cholesky factorization of a positive semidefinite matrix might (or might not) fail.)
